# Path to a document

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, clickonce

It is a WPF application.

I am trying to load a xml file like the following:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("../../doc/test.xml");
```

but when I publish using `Clickonce`, it won't be able to find the document.

How should I get the current location, like `basedir`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with,

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + @"\test.xml");
```

Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) this return path of executable file location.

Answer (score 0):

Try Out:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

This will get base directory

Comment: The BaseDirectory can be set at runtime, so it is not guaranteed to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`?

Answer (score 0):

If the XML file is some form of user configurable input, then that file should be in a Windows common application data folder (see Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData). So the path is not relative but a path constructed from a known base that the deployment code 'knows' about.

I like to create a folder in Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData for my company and application something like: \\

Perhaps we need more detail. I hope this helps.